# FileZilla: Can I run a remote shell command via FileZilla client?

Tags: shell, ftp, remote-access, filezilla, remote-connection

I have a very simple question. Can I run a remote shell command
on the server via FileZilla client. For instance can I do a:

> tar -zxvf myarchive.tar.gz

etc... (didn't think it was possible with plain FTP, was wondering about
the other protocols offered by FileZilla).

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Some*, but not many, FTP servers support `SITE EXEC command`. You can enter that in FileZilla using *Server > Enter custom command*. E.g.:

```
SITE EXEC tar -zxvf myarchive.tar.gz
```

Other than FTP, FileZilla supports only SFTP protocol, which does not have any way to execute command on the remote side.

---

Though it is common that if you have an SFTP access, you also have an SSH terminal access. Some SFTP clients (but not FileZilla) have a built-in terminal feature that allows you to execute commands over an SSH terminal session that seamlessly opens using the same credentials you used for SFTP.

For example in [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/), go to [*Commands > Open Terminal*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_console):

[image: WinSCP Console window]

You can even [save the command and easily reuse it](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_commands).

With FTP protocol, you can execute the `SITE ...` command from the same window.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score 3):

As this [link](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/4147) points out, the answer to the question is still no.
For executing remote shell commands use an ssh client.